# Framework for Automatically Generating PDF Documents On Chrome OS

Tags: pdf, chrome-os

I have used VBA to write software for automating paper invoice generation and printing using the MS office suite. Given a list of addressees, the software automatically generates and saves a PDF format invoice for each addressee.

I want to write software with the same functionality for deployment on Chrome OS. The requirements are:

1. User is able to fill in a form with the information of the addressee.
2. Software generates a PDF format invoice which includes formatted text and images (corporate logo) and saves each one to a specified location.

I have found potential methods for achieving this to be difficult to research, though I appreciate there may be many possible candidates. In this case, I think that the lowest-complexity (least individual libraries, packages, non-native chrome OS functionality) would be best. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean Chrome OS? You did not specify the chrome-os tag. Or do you just mean chrome, which is the tag you used? In either case, could you elaborate on the importance of chrome[-os]? Why is that a restriction? Finally, what do you mean by "fill in a form"? A web form? PDF form?

Comment: I mean Chrome OS, as this is the operating system being used by my 'client'. I have changed the tag on the question, I apologise for the confusion. I have decided to use a web (HTML)  form, please see my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question. It is possible to package a web app as a chrome app that can be added to google chrome on chrome OS. There are existing javascript libraries for PDF generation, one of which is jsPDF (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). An HTML form can be used to take data from the user. A standard format PDF file that includes this information as text can then be generated.